# Algorithm to derive taylor series coefficient equation

Tags: reference-request, taylor-expansion, computational-mathematics

I'm wondering, does anyone know whether there is an algorithm, or some sort of solver, that takes a function and returns an expression for the coefficient of the nth term of its Taylor series? For example the funciton $e^x$ will give us the expression $1/n!$. This is fairly simple to derive using the definition of the taylor expansions, but other functions are arduous and require manipulation of generalized binomial coefficients and application of other rules. Anyone has an idea of how to mechanize the process? There are integral solvers online, even though integration is known not to be a strictly mechanical process like derivation, so why not for this?

My goal is to find the nth coefficients of a taylor expansion efficiently. If there does not exist a solver to find the expression for the nth coefficient, then I also find satisfactory, as an answer, an algorithm that takes any function and computes its nth derivative at $0$ in $O(n)$ time, which would allow me to find the nth taylor coefficient fairly efficiently.

Comment: I’m supposing that you’d like an algorithm that is not recursive: would give the $m$-th coefficient without your computing all the previous ones. As someone who has been computing power-series coefficients for a long time, I’d say, no, there’s no such general algorithm, but it will be wonderful if one is found. The two series $(1+x)^{1/n}$ and $\sin x$ have fairly well-describable algorithms, but what about $(1+\sin x)^{1/n}$? Maybe some combinatorial specialist can say I’m way off base here, and I will be happy.

Comment: I'd prefer a non-recursive algorithm.. That being said, the factorial function itself is recursive, so I'd accept any recursive formula provided it is computable in O(n) time. Yeah, I thought there'd be no general algorithm, but some sort of online solver or algebraic system that handles a large array of cases would be welcome too!

Comment: Have you tried Mathematica? It can do a good job.

Comment: @Somos Where can I access it for free? (Or reasonably priced) and what part of the question is it capable of doing?

Comment: Goto [WolframCloud](https://www.wolframcloud.com/) and try something like `D[Sin[k*x+a],{x,n}]/n!`.

Comment: In the specific case I mentioned, of composition of power series, you should look in Knuth’s book, Seminumerical Algorithms (vol. 4 of his magnum opus), on manipulation of power series.